# Stuck with factoring an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$(x^{ 2 }+2)^{ 5/2 }+2x(x^{ 2 }+2)^{ 3/2 }+x^{ 2 }\sqrt { x^{ 2 }+2 } $$

I believe that the first step to factoring this would require me to take the factor with the smallest exponent out of the expression. I am able to factor expressions of a less complex nature but I feel completely paralyzed by this one. I do not need the direct answer. I have an answer key for that. I would like to attempt to do this on my own with guidance.

Comment: If you factor out $\sqrt{x^2+2}$ first, it'll be a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: $(x^2+2)^{5/2}+2x(x^2+2)^{3/2}+x^2(x^2+2)^{1/2} = (x^2+2)^{1/2}\left[(x^2+2)^2+2x(x^2+2)+x^2\right]$.

**Hint 2**: $A^2+2AB+B^2 = (A+B)^2$.

Comment: I didn't realize that the factor with the smallest exponent was actually $\sqrt { x^{ 2 }+2 } $ Now I am completely lost with how to further simplify the right side of that.

Comment: I added a 2nd hint. Let me know if that isn't helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand it.

Comment: Compare the bit you don't know how to simplify with the hint 2, try to match up parts of one with parts of the other. What matches the $2AB$ that's in hint 2, for example?

Comment: Have you got it yet, Cherry?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have been very busy with work. I will attempt to solve this problem again in a few hours and report back to you. Thank you for your concern.